# How to include required reference for project in it's release .dll

Tags: c#, specflow

In my solution I have a project "commons" and project has reference like SpecFlow.CustomPlugin. When I build the project Com.Org.Commons.dll will get generated. 
But when I refer this .dll file to another project (please look into attached image [solution structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG3Cy.jpg)
) 
[image]

"SFP" which has class NUnitPropertyGenerator.cs also need reference of SpecFlow.CustomPlugin which is already included in commons project.

I build the project commons and Com.Org.Commons.dll will get generated. But when I include the Com.Org.Commons.dll into SFP project below code gives me error and it doesn't refer to Com.Org.Commons.dll.

```
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Plugins;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.UnitTestProvider;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure;

[assembly: GeneratorPlugin(typeof(Com.Org.SFP.CustomNUnitProperties.SpecFlow.NUnitPropertyGenerator))]

namespace Com.Org.SFP.CustomNUnitProperties.SpecFlow
{
    public class NUnitPropertyGenerator : IGeneratorPlugin
    {
        public void Initialize(GeneratorPluginEvents generatorPluginEvents, GeneratorPluginParameters generatorPluginParameters)
        {
            generatorPluginEvents.CustomizeDependencies += (sender, args) =>
            {
                args.ObjectContainer.RegisterTypeAs<MasterProvider, IUnitTestGeneratorProvider>();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I thought TechTalk.SpecFlow will get refered if I include Com.Org.Commons.dll in SFP project which internally referes SpecFlow.CustomPlugin package.

Expected result should be:

SFP project should successfully build after including the Com.Org.Commons.dll and should resolve the code error which are related to TechTalk.SpecFlow. Logically both the project required SpecFlow.CustomPlugin package but as I am seperated out the details implementation to commons project and considering common project has a reference package included in dependencies I should be able to resolve the error in SFP project after referencing the Com.Org.Commons.dll in SFP project.

Please find .csproj file content

commons.csproj (https://gist.github.com/gittadesushil/100df50d4de72d61a9d57aa08c82cada)
SFP.csproj (https://gist.github.com/gittadesushil/dda1af31b5351f6ef9c71e44e2ceccda)

Comment: Please post the content of the two csproj files. Are they in the sdk- style format?

Comment: @AndreasWillich yes they are sdk style project. Please find content of csproj files on below gist. Project commons.csproj. https://gist.github.com/gittadesushil/100df50d4de72d61a9d57aa08c82cada.     SFP.csproj file content      https://gist.github.com/gittadesushil/dda1af31b5351f6ef9c71e44e2ceccda

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the namespaces/classes defined in `SpecFlow.CustomPlugin` DLL, you will need to add a reference to that DLL directly in all projects where you are using its classes directly in code. For e.g., `TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure` looks like a namespace from `SpecFlow.CustomPlugin` that's being used in `SFP`. In this case `SFP` needs to have a reference to `SpecFlow.CustomPlugin`

If you were not using `TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure` directly in `SFP` then all you would need to do was to ensure that the `CopyLocal` property of the `SpecFlow.CustomPlugins` reference in `commons` was set to true.

Comment: I am not able to find CopyLocal property of the SpecFlow.CustomPlugins reference in commons

Comment: In SolutionExplorer, expand the references under your commons project. There you will see SpecFlow.CustomPlugin. Right click on it and select Properties. The property window will open and that will have a CopyLocal property. But as I mentioned, since you are referring to TechTalk classes directly, you may have to add the reference to your SPF project for it to build.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but When I package the SFP project and gives it to my client they get error like "Could not load file or assembly 'Com.Org.Commons, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. SFP.Tests 2 C:\Users\sushil\.nuget\packages\specflow.tools.msbuild.generation\2.4.1\build C:\Users\sushil\.nuget\packages\specflow.tools.msbuild.generation\2.4.1\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets"

Answer (score 0):

You are using a normal Reference (https://gist.github.com/gittadesushil/dda1af31b5351f6ef9c71e44e2ceccda#file-sfp-csproj-L25) and not a ProjectReference.

correct would be

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net45</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Com.Org.SFP.CustomNUnitProperties.SpecFlow</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Com.Org.SFP.CustomNUnitProperties.SpecFlow.2.4.SpecFlowPlugin</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>$(AssemblyName)</PackageId>
    <Description>$(PackageId)</Description>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)Output\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile></DocumentationFile>
    <IsTool>true</IsTool>
    <BuildOutputTargetFolder>tools\SpecFlowPlugin.2-4</BuildOutputTargetFolder>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Auto</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="Com.Org.Commons" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Normal References don't look at the dependency graph.

Comment: Now the project reference is part of SFP project. When I pack the SFP project using nuget for my client to use. When client install that SFP package then client get's "Could not load file or assembly 'Com.Org.Commons, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies....." error while building because Com.Org.Commons is not packaged.